# Sending back an ajax error response in rails contoller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I am attempting to send back an error response to an ajax call in a rails controller.

Below is my create action in my controller the javascript function with the ajax call.  I need to send back a error response so the error portion of the ajax request is called.  I can not figure out how to get this to work.

```
  def create
    @company = Company.find(params["company_id"])
    @campaign = @company.campaigns.build(campaign_params)
    if @campaign.save
      redirect_to campaign_get_campaigns_path(@company)
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render :json => {:error_message => @campaign.errors.full_messages, :success => false } }
      end
    end
  end


$(document).on('click', '#submitCampaign', function (e) {
    $form = $('.new_campaign');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    error: function(data) {
        newfunction(data);
    }
});
```

The response I am getting in the terminal is:

```
Completed 200 OK in 269ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.9ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define response `:status`. In this case is the best choice `422 Unprocessable entity`.

```
format.json { render :json => { :error_message => @campaign.errors.full_messages }, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
```

Comment: I am still getting POST http://localhost:3004/companies/100/campaigns 422 (OK) ...any idea?

Comment: 422 (OK)? It is quite weird. You should not get this type of response. Maybe you could try `:status => 422` but it should do the same thing.

Comment: How looks address in `$form.attr('action')`?

Comment: @edariedlless "/companies/100/campaigns" it is hitting the failure format block but for some reason it is not sending back the error

Comment: So it gets to error block of javascript ajax call? Try to add line with `console.log(data);` to the error block and tell me, what it prints to the browser console.

Comment: no it is not getting to the error block of the ajax call, that is what I am trying to get it to do, it is getting the respond_to in the controller.

Comment: Try to use `$form.attr('action') + '.json'` what will happen?